# Register an Interceptor with Castle Fluent Interface

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, fluent-interface, iinterceptor

I am trying to implement [nhibernate transaction handling](http://groups.google.com/group/autofac/browse_thread/thread/f10badba5fe0d546/e64f2e757df94e61?lnk=gst&q=transaction#e64f2e757df94e61) through Interceptors and couldn’t figure out how to register the interface through fluent mechanism.

I see a

```
Component.For<ServicesInterceptor>().Interceptors
```

but not sure how to use it. Can someone help me out? [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188957/castle-interceptors-with-fluent-interface) seemed a little complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do it in two steps:

- You need to register the interceptor as a service in the container:

> ```
> container.Register(Component.For<MyInterceptor>());
> ```

- You register the component you want to intercept. Using `Interceptors` method on fluent API you specify which of the registered interceptors (by key, or type) you want to intercept this component with:

> ```
> container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>()
>    .Interceptors<MyInterceptor>());
> ```

See [the documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-Interceptors-ProxyOptions.ashx) for more details.

Comment: @Krzysztof My interceptor is designed to pick all methods and check for a custom attribute.which means that the class might not implement an interface. Essentially any method that has transaction attribute goes inside a transaction. So how do i add an interceptor to intercept all methods in the app domain? Your example if for `IFoo`

Comment: DynamicProxy is able to intercept calls to methods on classes, but the requirement is that these methods must be virtual, so as long as your components satisfy that requirement you're good to go

Comment: @QuintinPar 7 years later... To intercept every component created use a IContributeComponentModelConstruction examples http://stackoverflow.com/a/26426700/90033 and https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/componentmodel-construction-contributors.md

Answer (score 1):

First register the interceptor:

> `container.Register(Component.For<IDbInterceptor>().ImplementedBy<DbInterceptor>().Named("transactionInterceptor"));`

Then register the objecting being intercepted:

> container.Register(Component.For<IMyService>().ImplementedBy<MyService>().Named("MyService"). Interceptors(new
>        InterceptorReference("transactionInterceptor")).Anywhere);