# Castle Windsor not intercepting DataException

Tags: castle-windsor

I have a class to intercept DataException which implements the IInterceptor interface, however the Intercept method is not being called.

I'm registering the interceptor class this way:

```
container.Register(Component.For<DatabaseErrorInterceptor>().LifestyleTransient());
```

Here is the interceptor class:

```
public class DatabaseErrorInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            try
            {
                invocation.Proceed();
            }
            catch (DataException exc)
            {
                throw this.MapearExcecao(excecao);
            }
        }

        private BusinessRuleException HandleException(DataException databaseError)
        {
            // ...

            return new BusinessRuleException(...);
        }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2575625/43846 might help

Comment: How can I register the exception? There isn't an interface for the exception.

Comment: You need to call Interceptors<DatabaseErrorInterceptor>() on your database service so the interceptor is called, you don't have to register the exception

Comment: Still not working with the code: container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ICommand<>)).Interceptors<DatabaseErrorInterceptor>());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the answer to this problem, it was missing a call to container.Kernel.ProxyFactory.AddInterceptorSelector(...);