# Registering an Interceptor For All Interface Implementations in Castle Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, interceptor

I'm fairly new to Castle Windsor and in particular using Interceptors and am wondering if it is possible to register an Interceptor across all implementations of a particular interface without specifying each implementation in turn. For example, I have an interface called `IComponent` which will be implemented by a number of classes. I have a `ComponentInterceptor` class written to act on these classes when they have executed a particular method. I would like to do something like:

```
_container.Register(
 Component.For<IComponent>()
                  .Interceptors("ComponentInterceptor")
                  .LifestyleSingleton())
```

Rather than having to do:

```
     _container.Register(
      Component.For<IComponent>()
                .ImplementedBy<ComponentA>()
                .Interceptors("ComponentInterceptor")
                .LifestyleSingleton()),
    _container.Register(
      Component.For<IComponent>()
                .ImplementedBy<ComponentB>()
                .Interceptors("ComponentInterceptor")
                .LifestyleSingleton())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found another approach, I wanted to register this interceptor for all components being registered and do this hopefully minimal fuss. To do this I follow [this article](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.ComponentModel-construction-contributors.ashx) and created a new class like this:

```
public class MyContributeComponentConstruct : IContributeComponentModelConstruction
{
    public void ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model)
    {
        if (model.Services.Any(s => s == typeof(IComponent)))
        {
            model.Interceptors.Add(InterceptorReference.ForType<ComponentInterceptor>());
        }
    }
}
```

and then add this contribute with the Castle Windsor container

```
container.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.AddContributor(new MyContributeComponentConstruct ());
```

Comment: A contributor is another approach. Although you shouldn't get the handlers and add an interceptor like that as the contributor is called when each component is registered. You should only modify the provided `model` otherwise your components will get multiple instances of the interceptor. I've updated your answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

You can register components in the container using conventions via the `Classes` class. The following registers all classes in the current assembly that implement `IComponent` under the service `IComponent` and with your `ComponentInterceptor` interceptor:

```
container.Register(
    Classes.FromThisAssembly()
        .BasedOn<IComponent>()
        .WithService.FromInterface()
        .Configure(c => c.Interceptors<ComponentInterceptor>())
);
```

The [Windsor documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx) provides a bunch of other examples and explains in detail what different classes are for.