# Proxy is created, and interceptor is in the __interceptors array, but the interceptor is never called

Tags: castle-windsor, fluent, iinterceptor, interceptor

This is the first time I've used interceptors with the fluent registration and I'm missing something.  With the following registration, I can resolve an IProcessingStep, and it's a proxy class and the interceptor is in the __interceptors array, but for some reason, the interceptor is not called.  Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks,
Drew

```
AllTypes.Of<IProcessingStep>()
 .FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
 .ConfigureFor<IProcessingStep>(c => c
  .Unless(Component.ServiceAlreadyRegistered)
  .LifeStyle.PerThread
  .Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<StepLoggingInterceptor>()).First
  ),
Component.For<StepMonitorInterceptor>(),
Component.For<StepLoggingInterceptor>(),
Component.For<StoreInThreadInterceptor>()


public abstract class BaseStepInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
 public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
 {
  IProcessingStep processingStep = (IProcessingStep)invocation.InvocationTarget;
  Command cmd = (Command)invocation.Arguments[0];
  OnIntercept(invocation, processingStep, cmd);
 }

 protected abstract void OnIntercept(IInvocation invocation, IProcessingStep processingStep, Command cmd);
}

public class StepLoggingInterceptor : BaseStepInterceptor
{
 private readonly ILogger _logger;

 public StepLoggingInterceptor(ILogger logger)
 {
  _logger = logger;
 }

 protected override void OnIntercept(IInvocation invocation, IProcessingStep processingStep, Command cmd)
 {
  _logger.TraceFormat("<{0}> for cmd:<{1}> - begin", processingStep.StepType, cmd.Id);

  bool exceptionThrown = false;

  try
  {
   invocation.Proceed();
  }
  catch
  {
   exceptionThrown = true;
   throw;
  }
  finally
  {
   _logger.TraceFormat("<{0}> for cmd:<{1}> - end <{2}> times:<{3}>",
        processingStep.StepType, cmd.Id,
        !exceptionThrown && processingStep.CompletedSuccessfully 
         ? "succeeded" : "failed",
        cmd.CurrentMetric==null ? "{null}" : cmd.CurrentMetric.ToString());
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188957/castle-interceptors-with-fluent-interface

Comment: I had looked that, and it doesn't seem to apply.  My interceptor is being instantiated and attached to the proxy.  Also, using any of the WithService events results in the service not being registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mauricio hinter you appear to be registering your components as a class service, not interface service. In this case unless method you're intercepting is virtual you won't be able to intercept it. Change your registration to:

```
AllTypes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
 .BasedOn<IProcessingStep>()
 .ConfigureFor<IProcessingStep>(c => c
  .Unless(Component.ServiceAlreadyRegistered)
  .LifeStyle.PerThread
  .Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<StepLoggingInterceptor>()).First
  ).WithService.Base(),
```

Comment: This led me to my final answer.  WithService.Base didn't work because I had several services of the same base type to register.  I went with WithService.FirstInterface() and created a layer of interfaces to define the type of step.  This makes the code easier to read and easier to override via config.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof for noting that methods must be marked as virtual in order for the Windsor interceptor to fire (when registering as a class service & not via an interface).  My Windsor interceptor did not work until I made this change.  Later, I went back and refactored things to use a generic interface and then the virtual modifier was not required.